# How to prevent client from accessing JSP page

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

In my web application, I use the `.load()` function in JQuery, to load some `JSP` pages inside a `DIV`.

```
$("#myDiv").load("chat.jsp");
```

In `chat.jsp`, no Java codes is executed unless this client has Logged in, means, I check the session.

```
String sessionId = session.getAttribute("SessionId");
if(sessionId.equals("100")){
  //execute codes
}else{
  //redirect to log in page
}
```

Those java codes that will be executed, they will `out.println();` some HTML elements.

I don't want the client to write `/chat.jsp` in the browser to access this page, as it will look bad, and the other stuff in the main page won't be there, and this could do a harm to the web app security.

How can I restrict someone from accessing `chat.jsp` directly, but yet keep it accessible via `.load()` ?

**UPDATE:**

JavaDB is a class that I made, it connects me to the Database.

This is chat.jsp

```
<body>

    <%

        String userId = session.getAttribute("SessionId").toString();
        if (userId != null) {
            String roomId = request.getParameter("roomId");
            String lastMessageId = request.getParameter("lastMessageId");
            JavaDB myJavaDB = new JavaDB();
            myJavaDB.Connect("Chat", "chat", "chat");
            Connection conn = myJavaDB.getMyConnection();
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String lastId = "";
            int fi = 0;
            ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("select message,message_id,first_name,last_name from users u,messages m where u.user_id=m.user_id and m.message_id>" + lastMessageId + " and room_id=" + roomId + " order by m.message_id asc");
            while (rset.next()) {
                fi = 1;
                lastId = rset.getString(2);
    %>
    <div class="message">
        <div class="messageSender">
            <%=rset.getString(3) + " " + rset.getString(4)%>
        </div>
        <div class="messageContents">
            <%=rset.getString(1)%>
        </div>
    </div>
    <%            }
    %>
    <div class="lastId">
        <% if (fi == 1) {%>
        <%=lastId%>
        <% } else {%>
        <%=lastMessageId%>
        <% }%></div>

    <% if (fi == 1) {%>
    <div class="messages">
    </div> 
    <% }
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
        }%>
</body>
```

Guys I don't know what Filter means.

**UPDATE**

If I decided to send a parameter that tells me that this request came from Jquery.

```
.load("chat.jsp", { jquery : "yes" });
```

And then check it in chat.jsp

```
String yesOrNo = request.getParameter("jquery");
```

Then they can simply hack this by using this URL.

```
/chat.jsp?jquery=yes
```

or something like that..

**UPDATE**

I tried Maksim's advice, I got this when I tried to access chat.jsp.

[image]

Is this the desired effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve this in my application I check for `X-Requested-With` field in http header the client sends to my page in its request. If its value is `XMLHttpRequest`, then it's very likely that it came from an ajax request (jQuery appends this header to its requests), otherwise I don't serve the page. Regular (direct) browser requests will leave this header field blank.

In ASP.Net it looks like this, you will have to change your code slightly for JSP:

```
if (Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] != "XMLHttpRequest")
{
     Response.Write("AJAX Request only.");
     Response.End();
     return;
}
```

**UPD**: After quick googling your code will probably be something like this

```
if(!request.getHeader("X-Requested-With").equals("XMLHttpRequest")){
    out.println("AJAX Request only.");
    out.flush(); 
    out.close(); 
    return; 
}
```

**UPD2**: Looks like `request.getHeader("X-Requested-With")` returns null in your case change the condition to something like this:

```
String ajaxRequest = request.getHeader("X-Requested-With");
if(ajaxRequest == null || !ajaxRequest.equals("XMLHttpRequest")){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you guys please check the codes that I added above and help me in making a JSP version of this answer?

Comment: @AliBassam add the code I provided before you check for user session and database queries.

Answer (score 1):

Is your code snippet a servlet? If that's so, use a security framework (such as Spring Security) or a  javax.servlet.Filter for applying security, then you can apply security to JSPs too.

Answer (score 1):

you should use Filter. Check session in filter code and redirect to login.

Answer (score 1):

according to http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/2918/how-to-set-a-request-header-in-a-jquery-ajax-call.aspx

> JQuery gives you the tools you need to create a request and retrieve a response through it's ajax library.  The raw $.ajax call gives you all kinds of callbacks to manipulate http messages.

So you can add a custom request header in your Ajaxa call like this

```
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  beforeSend: function (request)
  {
     request.setRequestHeader("Authority", "AJAXREQUEST");
  },
...........
```

And then in your servlet check to see if the request has the header Authority equals to AJAXREQUEST. This is how you read request headers http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/Servlet-Tutorial-Request-Headers.html